# Has anybody separated TypeScript from Node?

Tags: javascript, typescript, embedded-v8

I'm working with V8 in C++ and was asked about supporting TypeScript, which I'm unfamiliar with. After poking around, it looks like TypeScript runs as JavaScript but seems pretty tied to Node (e.g., for accessing the filesystem). There is no O/S filesystem in my project, which doesn't bother V8 because it isolates itself from such things and lets me translate things like "module names" into database calls rather than filesystem reads.

I see Deno also embeds TypeScript, but since its the same guy that wrote Node, I'm guessing that was a big leg up in providing TypeScript all the Node-cruft it has its hooks into. Seems a shame that TypeScript runs as JavaScript but ends up tied to a particular project rather than being embeddable in any JavaScript environment.

Has anybody written a neat shim for insulating TypeScript from Node to reduce the work of embedding it in a different product? Any ideas/pointers/thoughts welcome...

To be clear: I mean to say "separate the TypeScript *compiler* from Node". And by embed Typescript, I mean "embed the TypeScript compiler", which I believe is (in its compiled form) a bunch of JavaScript with serious dependencies on Node.

Comment: TypeScript code is generally transpiled to plain JavaScript by a separate tool.

Comment: When you run typescript in Deno, it'll transpile it to JS using tsc, then store those files in a temporary directory, then it'll run V8 on them. That's also probably the only viable way for you to support TS at the moment

Comment: Heard the guys over at Deno are working on implementing the TS compiler in Rust due to it being too slow

Comment: "*it looks like TypeScript runs as JavaScript*" - yes. "*but seems pretty tied to Node*" - no. Only to the same extent as JS is "tied to node". Typescript already *is* separated from node.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript already *is* separated from Node. In fact, it has nothing whatsoever to do with Node.

As an example, see the [TypeScript Playground](https://typescriptlang.org/play/), which is an online IDE written in TypeScript that runs in the browser (no Node in sight), including embedding the entire TypeScript toolchain (compiler etc.) which is also written in TypeScript and also runs in the browser (again, no Node in sight).

In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if while you were writing this question, there was actually TypeScript code running in your browser without Node. (Stack Overflow, Inc. is known to use TypeScript.)

You already mentioned Deno yourself, which includes the TypeScript compiler. No Node in sight.

Many, many web companies all over the world are using TypeScript to do browser-side scripting. Again, no Node in sight.

There is *exactly one* Node-specific thing in TypeScript, and that is that TypeScript knows how the Node.js module-lookup algorithm works. The only reason this exists is to ensure that *if* you use Node-style module lookup in your code, TypeScript will use the same algorithm to find the module for type-checking at compile time that Node.js will later use at runtime. Otherwise, it could lead to the situation that TypeScript will at compile-time find a module, type-check it and determine that is type-safe, but then at runtime, Node.js would actually load a different module.

This is undesirable, and that's why TypeScript knows about the Node.js module lookup algorithm. If and when another module lookup algorithm becomes popular, TypeScript will probably also implement that one. It doesn't seem likely, though, since e.g. the ECMAScript committee and the Denon developers have deliberately chosen to design much simpler module lookup. (In fact, ECMAScript and Denon arguably don't have "module lookup" at all, you always need to specify a URI resolving to the exact location of the module file.)

**!!! NOTE !!!** Whenever I wrote about "running TypeScript code" above, that was a simplification. As far as I know, there does not exist an interpreted TypeScript implementation, so you actually *can't* "run TypeScript" (in the same sense that you can't "run Go"). You have to compile it first. There are currently two compilers for TypeScript, `tsc` from Microsoft, and the TypeScript plugin for Babel. Both of those compilers compile TypeScript to ECMAScript. Also, both are *delivered* in ECMAScript (although `tsc` is written in TypeScript).

So, as long as you have *some way* of running ECMAScript, you can also run TypeScript.

There *was* a project to implement a native TypeScript implementation on top of the Rubinius Language Framework, but that project literally never produced more than a README stating the intention of implementing a native TypeScript implementation on top of the Rubinius Language Framework. I still think it would be nice to have a TypeScript runtime that isn't tied to ECMAScript, though.

Comment: "*you can't "run Go"*" - but then what is `go run`? :P

Comment: "So, as long as you have some way of running ECMAScript, you can also run TypeScript." That would be totes amazeballs! So I start up d8, type "load('tsc.js');", and quickly die because ts.sys is undefined. Which does not surprise me, as it sure looks like a lot of 'require' calls to Node modules in there. Hmmmm. Amending question to emphasize I want to separate the TypeScript *compiler* from Node.

Comment: [TypeScript Playground](https://typescriptlang.org/play/) embeds the compiler in your browser. No Node in sight. Deno embeds the compiler in, well, Deno. No Node in sight. There is no dependency of the compiler on Node.